# App Specific Bluetooth Pairing

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I was wondering if there's any way that I can control BLE device pairing specific to my app running on mobile device?

I do not want to write my own bluetooth profile so that only my app can talk to the BLE device instead i want to standard profiles available in BLE device but when it's paired to my phone, only my app should be able to communicate to it and none of the other apps should be able to communicate.

Answer (score 0):

No don't do that.
If you MUST then you should encrypt your data with a key only your app knows.
Bluetooth Low Energy is supposed to be open and free for all.

What is the purpose for you to block others? Preventing them to block your service?
Then use some pre-shared key to verify that it's your app in both sides and close the connection if it's not.

Comment: Let's say i will be updating FW on my BLE device through app and my app should be the only one who can update FW on BLE device. Even i don't want to other apps to send any malicious FW to my BLE device which might brick it. Hence I want to control in such a way that only my app should be in a position who can talk to BLE device but not any other app.

Comment: Even I was thinking if possible to hide my BLE device visibility from all other apps